# Django - AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'GET'

Tags: python, html, django

I am trying to get input from a checkbox from a website to go through django. I have already been through stackoverflow and found someone doing the same thing but for some reason it doesn't work for me and I get an error telling me that there is no 'GET' attribute for HttpRequest even though it says there is on the django documentation.

[image]

```
<input type="checkbox" id="option1" name="hedgecutb" value="???" class="custom-control-input">
```

python:

```
from django.http import HttpRequest
hedgecutb = HttpRequest.GET.get("hedgecutb")
```

error:

```
    hedgecutb = HttpRequest.GET.get("hedgecutb")
AttributeError: type object 'HttpRequest' has no attribute 'GET'
```

Comment: In your view, you would be referencing this from `request` object . not `HttpRequest`

Comment: You work with your `request.GET`, not with `HttpRequest`. `request` is a `HttpRequest` *object*.

Comment: yeah I already tried using the request object but I got an error message telling me that it was undefined so I tried just using HttpRequest